# Build string of length L with exactly N palindromes in it

Tags: string, algorithm, palindrome

Given length of a string *L* and *N* - number of palindromes, build a string with exactly *N* palindromic substrings in it. For example,

```
L = 4
N = 2
S = 'aabb' or 'abba'

L = 4
N = 3,4,5
S = impossible

L = 4
N = 6
S = 'aaaa' (palindromes are substrings S[0:2], S[2:4], S[1:3], S[0:3], S[1:4], S[0:4])
```

UPDATE: all target palindromes should be of length > 1

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sounds like it could be an interesting challenge for [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://www.codegolf.stackexchange.com) but I'm not sure what the question is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the alphabet restricted to `{a, b}` only? If it's not, then for N = 4 and L = 4 there is a solution.

Comment: You task it not clear. Required search unique palindromes or not? aabb have follwoing palindromes: "a", "b", "aa", "bb" (and one more time "a", "b")

Comment: S = 'abab' (palindromes are `aba`, `bab` and `abab`). "abab" is not a palindrome.

Comment: valid question, palindrome should be of length > 1

Comment: It looks like it is an NP-complete problem.

Comment: @Толя, you're right about `abab` is not a palindrome, sorry about that

Comment: @piotrekg2 it looks as NP-hard problem to me as well, thats why I wanted to check up with a community. I'm trying to think about formal proof now

Comment: @PavelPodlipensky To be strict, it is at most NP-complete because a solution can be verified in polynomial time.

Comment: What about L=4, N=3, and string is aaab ? Here will be 3 palindromes. In your example it is impossible.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a variable **s_i = {0, 1}** for each character in the string **S**, then if a substring **S[a..b]** is a palindrome, it must be that

```
(s_a = s_b) and (s_{a+1} = s_{b-1}) and ...
```

so for each substring you have a clause and exactly **N** of them must be satisfied. This reduces the problem to satisfiability.

I would also be curious if you can solve it as an optimization problem:
for each substring introduce a variable **x_i** = `{0, 1}` that stands for the fact that substring number `i` is a palindrome (let it be **S[a..b]**). Then introduce a variable **y_i** for the clause of that substring:

```
(s_a-s_b)^2 + (s_{a+1}-s_{b-1})^2 +  ...
```

Then you need to satisfy that `\sum_{x_i} = N` and minimize `\sum_{x_i * y_i}`. Obviously the minimum is **0** if a solution exists and the objective is always non-negative.

### Edit

the optimisation idea seems to be false, since you need to enforce that if `y_i = 0`, then it must be that `x_i = 0`, but satisfiability formulation should work